# Is Iblis everywhere?

Tags: quran, allah, shaitan

This question has been bothering me for a while and I can’t seem to find an answer, if anyone can provide information (and sources) it’d be much appreciated.

Does Iblees **only** use shayateens to lead us astray? Is waswasa and nightmares from **only shayateens** or does Iblees also directly do these actions to try make us reject Allah (swt)?

My family and I have been discussing this topic and my siblings say that Iblis cannot be everywhere, that Iblees cannot whisper to all of us, he has created shayateens for this. They say that because Iblees cannot be everywhere, he uses these shayateens to lead us astray; that *we all have one with us.*

In the verse where Iblees says that he will attack us from the front, left, right and between our hands when we are on the straight path, does this mean he will directly attack us or use his army of shayateens to? Alternatively, can we infer that **BOTH** Iblees and his shayateens will try and influence us? That iblees does not only use his army but also **directly** attempts to make mankind reject Allah (swt).

Jazak’allah Khairan

Comment: The Quran is completely unclear on how the singular Shaitan relates to the many Shaitans. Any answer would be a complete guess.

Answer (score 1):

Imām Sayyid Muĥammad Ibn Áābidīn al-Ĥanafī al-Shāmī [1198-1252 AH / 1784-1836 CE] writes in Radd al-Muĥtār:

> His statement, “And Iblīs is with the son of Ādam during the day.”
>
> That is, he is with all of them, except for the one whom Allāh táālā has protected from him, and He has given him the ability for that [i.e. to be with them all], just as He has given the Angel of Death [Malak al-Mawt] the ability for similar to that [i.e. to be in multiple places at once].

[2/245][image]